# CSS - Adding background images in the body of a website not working.

Tags: html, css, web, background-image

Here I have some css styles that alter the layout of all webpages for my website, with a wrapper that is 900px wide a header and the main body. So far I've changed the background colour in the body section which works great. However if I add some code to change the background image the result is just a blank white background not the image I put. Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o1snuexs/1/

And here is my CSS code:

```
/*CSS FOR ALL PAGES*/

/*BODY/WRAPPER SECTION*/

body {background-image: url("SiteBackground.png");}

#wrapper {width: 900px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          background-color: white;}

/*TOP BANNER SECTION*/

#banner {background-color: black;}

#logo {margin-top: -90px;
       margin-bottom: -140px;
       text-align: center;}

#ip {margin-bottom: -55px;
     margin-right: 687px;
     float: right;
     color: white;}

#teamspeak_logo {margin-left: 764px;}

/*TOP NAV BAR SECTION*/

* {margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;}

#nav_bar {background-color: #a22b2f;
          box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px;
          height: 45px;
          text-align: center;}

#nav_bar ul {padding: 0;}

#nav_bar > ul > li {display: inline-block;}

#nav_bar ul > li > a {color: white;
                      display: block;
                      text-decoration: none;
                      font-weight: normal;
                      padding-left: 10px;
                      padding-right: 10px;
                      line-height: 45px;
                      transition: all 0.5s ease;}

#nav_bar ul li ul {display: none;
                   list-style: none;
                   position: absolute;
                   background: white;
                   margin-left:0px;
                   box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px;
                   text-align: left;
                   z-index:1;}

#nav_bar ul li a.active-page {background-color: #8c1d20;}

#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li a {line-height: 2em;}

#nav_bar ul li a:hover {background: #8c1d20;}

#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {display: block;}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a {color: #252525;
                        display: block;}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a:hover {background: #4485f5;
                              color: white;}

/*BOTTOM FOOTER SECTION*/

#bottom_footer {height: 50px;
                border-top: solid 10px black;
                border-bottom: solid 10px black;
                margin-top: 20px;}

#created_by {text-align: center;
             margin: 17px;}

#social_media_youtube {float: left;
                       margin: -47px;
                       margin-left: 275px;}

#social_media_twitch {float: left;
                      margin: -44px;
                      margin-left: 335px;}

#social_media_twitter {float: right;
                       margin: -53px;
                       margin-right: 325px;}

#social_media_facebook {float: right;
                        margin: -47px;
                        margin-right: 285px;}

/*ELEMENT SELECTIONS SECTION*/

p {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   margin-left: 20px;
   margin-right: 20px;}

ul {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 37px;}

h3 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 20px;}

h4 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working fine.
You have to recheck the path of the image that you are using in background. else its all good.

its working for me

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/vipin_raunchhela/3q51s4ja/1/][1]
```

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't work just a white background still. One thing I have noticed is that yours is actually using a url where as mine is a local image from my harddrive.

Comment: Your input gave me a clue as to what I needed to do thanks. It turns out I have to put the entire file path in from the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper is covering the background image. Remove the background colour from the wrapper and it works.

```
#wrapper {width: 900px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: white;}  <------remove this
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the wrapper colour, I want the wrapper to stay as it is but have the background image fill the rest of the page so it's either side and above where the header is.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out putting the entire file path in works.

As seen here:

body {background:url('E:/Documents/CRAFT412-Website/images/SiteBackground.png');}